# Can't figure out why PCB is not working

Tags: arduino, pcb-design

New to electrical engineering and designed the following circuit board to improve my skill, particularly with an Arduino Micro:
[image: PCB]
The idea is relatively simple: the Arduino Micro drives eight buttons attached through a 5 Pin Molex Picoblade connector at D2 to D9, with 10K (pull up?) resistors to the connections, grounded and energized at 5V. However, I can't seem to get the high signal when simply bridging in the molex the GND line to the pins (thus "pressing" the button, as far as the microcontroller is concerned).

What mistakes did I make? What can I do better next time?

Comment: Your design uses pullup resistors, hence shunting an input to ground is indeed what a switch should do, **but that would result in a *low* signal**, vs the high signal that would be present from the pullup resistor when a switch is open.

Comment: Please post a schematic showing your intent

Comment: Where is the whole thing getting power?

Comment: The power is coming from a 5V MicroUSB cable, at 2 amps

Comment: Start with no bridge. What are the values of the 8 inputs? Now bridge one input. What do you get? What is the difference between the two conditions?

Comment: Arduino must be configured not to drive those lines. It may be a default state, but worth checking

Comment: There is no Micro-USB connector on the circuit board you've shown.

Comment: There is no physical connection of power to the 5V pin (the brownish track) so it could never work.

Comment: @CL. - True. However I believe the OP's PCB has a socket on the right side, where the mentioned [Arduino Micro](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMicro) is plugged-in. The Micro-USB socket is on the Arduino Micro, and so the OP's PCB *receives* its power via the 5V pin of the Arduino Micro (see its [schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-micro-schematic.pdf)) - i.e. the 5V pin on the OP's PCB is a 5V *input* from the Arduino Micro plugged-in there, which itself is powered via *its* Micro-USB socket, as mentioned by the OP.

Comment: The PCB isn't working, because you didn't do a schematic.  [@stark answer.]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to improve your design is scrap the pull-up resistors from the PCB and use the internal 20k pull-ups of the MCU instead. Then you can get rid of both the 5V trace and the external resistor footprints, reducing possible errors. You need to configure D2..D9 as `INPUT_PULLUP` instead of `INPUT` in your `setup` function, like this:

```
pinMode (2, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

As to why it doesn't work (apart from the obvious, that has already been pointed to you by others: when you close the "switch" you are pulling it LOW, not HIGH) it's **impossible to tell without looking at your code**. Once you simplify you circuit getting rid of the external pull-ups, if you keep not observing a level transition when "operating the switch" then it'll mean that something is failing in the code of your `setup` and/or `loop` functions.